# How to make red-black tree generic in java

Tags: java, generics, red-black-tree, generic-collections

I am working on red-black tree and wrote its full working code which I have shown below. I went through Generics tutorial and understood that with single class declaration, it is possible to specify a set of related method. How can I apply it to my red-black tree algorithm ? What happens in the generics case? If possible could you help me with this please ? This is the full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RedBlackTree {

    private final int RED = 0;
    private final int BLACK = 1;


    private class Node {

        int key = -1, color = BLACK;
        Node left = nil, right = nil, parent = nil;

        Node(int key) {
            this.key = key;
        } 
    }

    private final Node nil = new Node(-1); 
    private Node root = nil;

    public void printTree(Node node)
    {
        if (node == nil) {
            return;
        }
        printTree(node.left);
        System.out.print(((node.color==RED)?"Color: Red ":"Color: Black ")+"Key: "+node.key+" Parent: "+node.parent.key+"\n");
        printTree(node.right);
    }

    private Node findNode(Node findNode, Node node) 
    {
        if (root == nil) {
            return null;
        }

        if (findNode.key < node.key) {
            if (node.left != nil) {
                return findNode(findNode, node.left);
            }
        } else if (findNode.key > node.key) {
            if (node.right != nil) {
                return findNode(findNode, node.right);
            }
        } else if (findNode.key == node.key) {
            return node;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void insert(Node node) 
    {
        Node temp = root;
        if (root == nil) {
            root = node;
            node.color = BLACK;
            node.parent = nil;
        } else {
            node.color = RED;
            while (true) {
                if (node.key < temp.key) {
                    if (temp.left == nil) {
                        temp.left = node;
                        node.parent = temp;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        temp = temp.left;
                    }
                } else if (node.key >= temp.key) {
                    if (temp.right == nil) {
                        temp.right = node;
                        node.parent = temp;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        temp = temp.right;
                    }
                }
            }
            fixTree(node);
        }
    }

    private void fixTree(Node node) 
    {
        while (node.parent.color == RED) {
            Node uncle = nil;
            if (node.parent == node.parent.parent.left) {
                uncle = node.parent.parent.right;

                if (uncle != nil && uncle.color == RED) {
                    node.parent.color = BLACK;
                    uncle.color = BLACK;
                    node.parent.parent.color = RED;
                    node = node.parent.parent;
                    continue;
                } 
                if (node == node.parent.right) {
                    //Double rotation needed
                    node = node.parent;
                    rotateLeft(node);
                } 
                node.parent.color = BLACK;
                node.parent.parent.color = RED;
                //if the "else if" code hasn't executed, this
                //is a case where we only need a single rotation 
                rotateRight(node.parent.parent);
            } else {
                uncle = node.parent.parent.left;
                 if (uncle != nil && uncle.color == RED) {
                    node.parent.color = BLACK;
                    uncle.color = BLACK;
                    node.parent.parent.color = RED;
                    node = node.parent.parent;
                    continue;
                }
                if (node == node.parent.left) {
                    //Double rotation needed
                    node = node.parent;
                    rotateRight(node);
                }
                node.parent.color = BLACK;
                node.parent.parent.color = RED;

                rotateLeft(node.parent.parent);
            }
        }
        root.color = BLACK;
    }

    void rotateLeft(Node node) 
    {
        if (node.parent != nil) {
            if (node == node.parent.left) {
                node.parent.left = node.right;
            } else {
                node.parent.right = node.right;
            }
            node.right.parent = node.parent;
            node.parent = node.right;
            if (node.right.left != nil) {
                node.right.left.parent = node;
            }
            node.right = node.right.left;
            node.parent.left = node;
        } else {//Need to rotate root
            Node right = root.right;
            root.right = right.left;
            right.left.parent = root;
            root.parent = right;
            right.left = root;
            right.parent = nil;
            root = right;
        }
    }

    void rotateRight(Node node)
    {
        if (node.parent != nil) {
            if (node == node.parent.left) {
                node.parent.left = node.left;
            } else {
                node.parent.right = node.left;
            }

            node.left.parent = node.parent;
            node.parent = node.left;
            if (node.left.right != nil) {
                node.left.right.parent = node;
            }
            node.left = node.left.right;
            node.parent.right = node;
        } else {//Need to rotate root
            Node left = root.left;
            root.left = root.left.right;
            left.right.parent = root;
            root.parent = left;
            left.right = root;
            left.parent = nil;
            root = left;
        }
    }




    void replace(Node target, Node with){ 
          if(target.parent == nil){
              root = with;
          }else if(target == target.parent.left){
              target.parent.left = with;
          }else
              target.parent.right = with;
          with.parent = target.parent;
    }

    boolean delete(Node z){
        if((z = findNode(z, root))==null)
            return false;
        Node x;
        Node y = z; 
        int y_original_color = y.color;

        if(z.left == nil){
            x = z.right;  
            replace(z, z.right);  
        }else if(z.right == nil){
            x = z.left;
            replace(z, z.left); 
        }else{
            y = treeMinimum(z.right);
            y_original_color = y.color;
            x = y.right;
            if(y.parent == z)
                x.parent = y;
            else{
                replace(y, y.right);
                y.right = z.right;
                y.right.parent = y;
            }
            replace(z, y);
            y.left = z.left;
            y.left.parent = y;
            y.color = z.color; 
        }
        if(y_original_color==BLACK)
            fixDelColor(x);  
        return true;
    }

    void fixDelColor(Node x){
        while(x!=root && x.color == BLACK){ 
            if(x == x.parent.left){
                Node w = x.parent.right;
                if(w.color == RED){
                    w.color = BLACK;
                    x.parent.color = RED;
                    rotateLeft(x.parent);
                    w = x.parent.right;
                }
                if(w.left.color == BLACK && w.right.color == BLACK){
                    w.color = RED;
                    x = x.parent;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(w.right.color == BLACK){
                    w.left.color = BLACK;
                    w.color = RED;
                    rotateRight(w);
                    w = x.parent.right;
                }
                if(w.right.color == RED){
                    w.color = x.parent.color;
                    x.parent.color = BLACK;
                    w.right.color = BLACK;
                    rotateLeft(x.parent);
                    x = root;
                }
            }else{
                Node w = x.parent.left;
                if(w.color == RED){
                    w.color = BLACK;
                    x.parent.color = RED;
                    rotateRight(x.parent);
                    w = x.parent.left;
                }
                if(w.right.color == BLACK && w.left.color == BLACK){
                    w.color = RED;
                    x = x.parent;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(w.left.color == BLACK){
                    w.right.color = BLACK;
                    w.color = RED;
                    rotateLeft(w);
                    w = x.parent.left;
                }
                if(w.left.color == RED){
                    w.color = x.parent.color;
                    x.parent.color = BLACK;
                    w.left.color = BLACK;
                    rotateRight(x.parent);
                    x = root;
                }
            }
        }
        x.color = BLACK; 
    }

    Node treeMinimum(Node subTreeRoot)
    {
        while(subTreeRoot.left!=nil){
            subTreeRoot = subTreeRoot.left;
        }
        return subTreeRoot;
    }

    public void consoleUI() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\n1. Insert () method\n"
                    + "2. ToString() method\n"
                    + "3. Contains() method\n"
                    + "4. Delete() method\n"
                    + "5. Exit \n");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();

            int item;
            Node node;
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    item = scan.nextInt();
                    while (item != 001) {
                        node = new Node(item);
                        insert(node);
                        item = scan.nextInt();
                    }
                    printTree(root);
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    printTree(root);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    item = scan.nextInt();
                    while (item != 001) {
                        node = new Node(item);
                        System.out.println((findNode(node, root) != null) ? "found" : "not found");
                        item = scan.nextInt();
                    }
                    break;

                    case 4:
                    item = scan.nextInt();
                    while (item != 001) {
                        node = new Node(item);
                        System.out.print("\nDeleting item " + item);
                        if (delete(node)) {
                            System.out.print(": deleted!");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print(":  entered item does not exist!");
                        }
                        item = scan.nextInt();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    printTree(root);
                    break;

                    case 5:
                    return;

            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RedBlackTree redblacktree = new RedBlackTree();
        redblacktree.consoleUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `public class RedBlackTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the openjdk implementation of `TreeMap` as it using a red-black tree with generics. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java

Answer (score 2):

**Essential steps to genericise:**

1. Class declaration:

   ```
   class RedBlackTree<KeyType extends Comparable<KeyType>, ValueType>
   ```

   Assumes that each node stores two values - a key, which determines location within the ordered tree and a nullable value which does not.  `ValueType` is optional, but it does give an efficient map implementation in the form of a tree.
   (Aside based upon comment by  4castle: it doesn't make sense to replace `Comparable<KeyType>` with `Comparable<? super KeyType>` because it's impossible to insert non-`KeyType`s into the tree)
2. Class implementation (`Node` class): replace the two cases of `int key` with `KeyType key`; add instance variable `ValueType val` (optional).  If ValueType added, Node constructor becomes:

   ```
   Node(KeyValue key, KeyValue val) {
      this.key = key;
      this.val = val;
   }
   ```
3. Class usage (method `consoleUI`), type-instantiate `KeyType` and `ValueType` during `Node` declaration, E.g.:

   ```
   Node<Integer, String> node;
   ... 
       node = new Node(item, val);
   ```

   or

   ```
   Node<Integer, Void> node;
   ... 
       node = new Node(item, null);
   ```

*** Result ***

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RedBlackTree<KeyType extends Comparable<KeyType>, ValueType> {

    private static final int RED = 0;
    private static final int BLACK = 1;
    private static final Node nil = new Node(-1); ******
    private Node root = nil;

    private class Node {
      KeyType key;
      ValueType val;
      color = BLACK;
      Node left = nil, right = nil, parent = nil;

      Node(int key) {
         this.key = key;
         this.val = val;
      } 
    }

    // believe remaining code is unchanged (except for adding val param)
    // ...
    // ...

    public void consoleUI() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\n1. Insert () method\n"
                + "2. ToString() method\n"
                + "3. Contains() method\n"
                + "4. Delete() method\n"
                + "5. Exit \n");
            int choice = scan.nextInt();

            int item;
            Node<Integer, Void> node;
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    item = scan.nextInt();
                    while (item != 001) {
                        node = new Node(item, null);

         etc
```

**General suggestion:** break your class into 2.  It doesn't make sense to have tree usage buried inside the tree class itself.  Create a class call `RedBlackTreeTest` and move `consoleUI` and `main` into it.

Comment: Thank you @Glen Best for your answer, I applied them to my code however, it did not work due to errors. Mainly occurring errors are "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to KeyType where KeyType is a type-variable:" I could not fix them unfortunately. If possible, could you show the working code, please ? I really want to understand this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @sprinter unfortunately, I could not fix them, I mean I have problems when converting int to <T>. Can you  show your implementation, please ?